# Why it doesn't work, function call and module import?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a file in this location /src/auth/auth.js with this function

```
  logout() {
// Clear Access Token and ID Token from local storage
localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
localStorage.removeItem('expires_at')
localStorage.removeItem('chatkit_user')
//TODO: callback to reset the app state.
```

}

and a button in /src/components/userHeader/index.js

```
                <button onClick={() => logout()} >
```

Log Out

then i wanna make my button actives that function so i tried

```
import { logout } from '/src/auth/auth.js';
```

i though that should make my button actives that function because i did just import that file but then my server netlify throw me this

```
./src/components/UserHeader/index.js
```

10:38:20 AM: You attempted to import /src/auth/auth.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
10:38:20 AM: You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
10:38:20 AM: npm
10:38:20 AM:  ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:38:20 AM: npm
10:38:20 AM: ERR! errno 1
10:38:20 AM: npm
10:38:20 AM:  ERR! pusher-chatkit-demo-with-auth0@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
10:38:20 AM: npm ERR!

and i really tried to solve it my self but i can't i'm following a github tutorial https://github.com/Cazadorx/chatkit-sample-client there is all pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
import { logout } from '../../auth/auth.js';
```

or

```
import { logout } from '../../auth/auth';
```

Comment: Failed to compile.
2:23:36 PM: ./src/components/UserHeader/index.js
2:23:36 PM: Cannot find file './auth/auth.js' in './src/components/UserHeader'.
2:23:36 PM: npm
2:23:36 PM: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2:23:36 PM: npm
2:23:36 PM: ERR! errno 1
2:23:36 PM: npm
2:23:36 PM: ERR! pusher-chatkit-demo-with-auth0@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
2:23:36 PM: npm ERR!
2:23:36 PM:  Exit status 1

Comment: I edited the answer, I assumed you were in the same directory path  also export logout like @ThayalanGR suggested

Comment: i'm gonna try your new answer

Comment: Failed to compile.
2:41:26 PM: ./src/auth/auth.js
2:41:26 PM: Syntax error: Unexpected token (67:7)
2:41:26 PM:   65 |
2:41:26 PM:   66 |
2:41:26 PM: > 67 | const logout = () => {
2:41:26 PM:      |       ^
2:41:26 PM:   68 | // Clear Access Token and ID Token from local storage
2:41:26 PM:   69 | localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
2:41:26 PM:   70 | localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
2:41:26 PM: npm
2:41:26 PM:  ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2:41:26 PM: npm
2:41:26 PM:  ERR! errno
2:41:26 PM:  1
2:41:26 PM: npm

Comment: that looks like

Comment: Just take out the braces import logout and not {logout}

Comment: : Failed to compile.
3:18:56 PM: ./src/auth/auth.js
3:18:56 PM: Syntax error: Unexpected token (73:8)
3:18:56 PM:   71 | //TODO: callback to reset the app state.
3:18:56 PM:   72 | }
3:18:56 PM: > 73 | export {logout} ;
3:18:56 PM:      |        ^
3:18:56 PM:   74 | }
3:18:56 PM:   75 |

Answer (score 0):

export the function from the file

```
const logout = () => {
// Clear Access Token and ID Token from local storage
localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
localStorage.removeItem('expires_at')
localStorage.removeItem('chatkit_user')
//TODO: callback to reset the app state.
}

export { logout };
```

Comment: Failed to compile.
2:32:25 PM: ./src/components/UserHeader/index.js
2:32:25 PM: Cannot find module: 'src/auth/auth.js'. Make sure this package is installed.
2:32:25 PM: You can install this package by running: yarn add src/auth/auth.js.
2:32:25 PM: npm
2:32:25 PM:  ERR! code
2:32:25 PM:  ELIFECYCLE
2:32:25 PM: npm
2:32:25 PM:  ERR! errno 1

Comment: i don't get it the location is ok what is the problem

Comment: specify the path correctly relative to the current directory with the target directory.